# Do you have references issues with Visual Studio 2008 and C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reference

I'm working on a project and it seems that every time someone checks out the project from source control to build it on their local box they have issues building because references are no longer resolved.

I can't figure out if it's a configuration issues or a Visual Studio 2008 issue. Is anyone else having this problem? If so, is there something you can do to fix this issue?

Note: it might have something to do with explicit paths to the DLLs being referenced or how they are referenced ... I'm not quite sure.

Comment: What kind of refernces are these (GAC, Project, file system, COM)?

Comment: Not sure why this is a community wiki exactly...

Comment: While I was writing the question SO claims that it was subjective and it was likely to be closed, so I made it a community wiki. Also, I'm not necessarily just looking for an answer to my problem ... I'm trying to gauge if other people are having these problems or is there something we are doing that others are not.

Comment: What kinds of references are getting messed up?  Project references within the solution?  references to 3rd-party controls?  GAC references?  
Are all of the development machines either 32-bit or 64-bit, or is there a mix?

Comment: Some are 3rd party references and others are common references that are used in multiple projects. They are referencing DLLs which get generating from building other projects or ones that are already built and shipped from a 3rd party. I believe most of us have 64 bit machines now, but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically I see this with one of three things

1. Packages on Machine A, not on Machine B
2. Things in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) on machine A, not in Machine B
3. Packages not checked into source control

Visual studio typically handles relational pathing well, and I've not had it *just* be a path issue.

Also make sure you are NOT checking in .SUO files and .csproj.user.  These will both monkey with references sometimes.

Comment: +1. Make sure it's not in the GAC or in the Registry (.NET tab in Add Reference dialog) on the original developer's PC. Check that the developer didn't reference a bin path or other file that's no longer there or wasn't checked in.

Comment: There are no .SUO files or .csproj.user files checked into source control, which is good. I'm not sure if it's in the GAC or Registry on the original developer's PC? Is there a way for me to check that based on what I check out of source control?

Comment: @Brian - If you select a reference and check the properties it should show you where it is loaded from.  As to whether or not it is part of the standard .NET install... that's a bit harder to determine.  However you should get warnings about exactly what is missing when you load on the other machines.  Check the properties on those references.  If they are being loaded from outside of your project tree then you will need to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Start looking in your .csproj files. We had this problem years ago, but soon learned that it was more operator error than anything else. Specific items to look for are: `<HintPath>` and
`<ProjectReference>`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your problems could definitely be caused by the paths to your referenced DLLs.  Have a look at the properties of the DLL in the References folder of the project (right click on the reference item in your Visual Studio solution and select Propertiers) to see the path that is being used for the DLL. To get around this problem one option is to make sure everyone has the same path on their local drive to the referenced DLLs.  You can also use the Reference Paths page on the properties of your project to add additional reference paths to the projects.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if anyone has accidentally committed/checked in any csproj.user files with their local paths inside `<ReferencePath> under <propertygroup>`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the referenced DLLs are not checked into source control - I put all external dlls in a lib folder under the project root and reference those. I've never had a problem with Visual Studio resolving the relative paths correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. References to your own code in same solution should be "Project References". Never add these as references to the DLL directly. For your own/in-house code, add as much as is practical to the solution. Otherwise take strategy 2C.
2. References to other code should be discussed and a strategy chosen for each type of reference. You have a couple of options:

a. Add the DLL directly as part of your solution, perhaps in a LIB directory. Check it into source control. Every team member will have a consistent experience.

b. For 3rd party components, everyone should probably run the vendor installation package with consistent installation paths, etc.  (Many 3rd parties install to the GAC, so this becomes part of the reference. Otherwise it would be c:\Program files\etc etc)

c. Publish the DLLs to a shared directory, i.e. a network share. Reference DLLs from this path only. Ensure Copy-Local is true.

Verify the strategy has been followed by reviewing the CSPROJ file XML for tags such as ProjectReference and HintPath.

Finally, each team member should be aware of this. If anyone does something different, then you will feel the pain again and again with each new "Get Latest".